# ‘Se mia nonna avesse le ruote, sarebbe una carriola’

Tags: etymology, idioms

*Se mia nonna  avesse le ruote, sarebbe  una carriola*:

> - ‘If my grandmother had wheels, she would be a [wheelbarrow](http://www.theflorentine.net/articles/article-view.asp?issuetocId=6635).' That's what Italians say when they want to interrupt your rambling hypothetical scenario. After all, if a rolling granny doesn't bring you to a standstill, nothing will. '

This is a curious but quite common saying. What is its origin?

Comment: Interessante! Purtroppo non ho trovato l'origine... Segnalo  comunque come si possa rendere il modo di dire molto più efficace e colloquiale usando impropriamente l'indicativo, ancora meglio se nella versione: "se mio nonno aveva cinque palle era un flipper" con tutti gli errori di grammatica del caso.

Comment: Io ho sentito anche "se mia nonna aveva i finestrini era un aeroplano" (anche qui, errori intenzionali), però la versione con la carriola è sicuramente la più popolare.

Comment: Penso che l'indicativo (sbagliato dal punto di vista della grammatica) sia perfetto in questo caso; il congiuntivo e il condizionale tolgono qualcosa. Carina la versione con i finestrini e l'aeroplano!

Comment: Prima volta che sento dirlo. Suppongo però sia qualcosa romano-toscano.

Comment: @black: Sembra provenire dalla Liguria: https://books.google.es/books?id=D9XmKO2wmXIC&pg=PA26&dq=%22Se+mia+nonna+avesse+le+ruote%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hr_sVM79EMWtU8W8g4AD&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22Se%20mia%20nonna%20avesse%20le%20ruote%22&f=false

Comment: Da me si dice "se mia nonna avesse avuto le ruote, io sarei una carriola"

Comment: Adding for completeness: "Se mio nonno aveva le ruote, era un carretto."

Comment: Che cosa vi fa pensare che nel periodo ipotetico l'indicativo sia un “errore”?

Comment: C'è anche la versione milanese: "se mi nonno g'aveva la pertegheta, l'era un tramvai".

Comment: @DaG: Il mio libro di grammatica afferma che, nel periodo ipotetico, si usa sempre il congiuntivo e il condizionale, eccetto se l'ipotesi è molto probabile. In tal caso, si può usare l'indicativo presente o il futuro semplice: *Se domani non piove, andiamo in gita.* *Se domani pioverà, staremo in casa.*

Comment: @DaG - perché   hai cambiato il titolo?

Comment: @Charo hai ragione. Ma usare l'indicativo in questo caso rende la frase ancora più immediata e divertente ANCHE perché è grammaticalmente scorretta.

Comment: I hope you guys won't forget [THIS](http://nonciclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/E_la_marmotta_confeziona_la_cioccolata), that comes from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Gzew4u44kQ).

Warning: the satirical website I linked is most likely NSFW, but it is hilarious :)

Comment: @Josh61: L'ho scritto nel commento alla modifica: La domanda è su una frase idiomatica italiana; non ha molto senso “tradurla”. Per chiarire: se fosse una domanda sulle carriole, andrebbe benissimo parlarne in inglese, ma invece è una domanda su quella specifica sequenza di parole italiane.

Comment: @Charo e altri: 1) In linguistica non ha molto senso parlare di “errore”, bensì di fenomeni da studiare; 2) Il tipo “Se lo sapevo non venivo” è parte integrante dell'italiano da sempre, ovviamente marcato in senso colloquiale (il cosiddetto “substandard”), e si trova in tutti i maggiori autori. Vietarlo sarebbe come dire che una camicia è “giusta” e una t-shirt è “sbagliata”: per farsi ricevere dal presidente della repubblica forse, in assoluto certamente no. Si veda per esempio [qui](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/imperfetto_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/), 3.3 e Serianni, XIV, 151.

Comment: Versione tarantina (tradotta): Se mio nonno avesse tre palle sarebbe un flipper

Comment: @DaG: Forse non si dovrebbe parlare d'"errore", ma di "forma substandard". In un esame di lingua, però, sicuramente questa "forma substandard" sarebbe considerata sbagliata.

Comment: "Avesse avuto 5 palle mio nonno sarebbe stato un flipper" ('Si teneva 5 palle 'o nonno mio era 'nu flipper') cantata dai Bisca/99Posse nel brano "O Sfruttament" dal CD "La bomba intelligente"

Comment: Ho impressione che ci si affanni invano a trovare un’unica origine; l’espressività e la perspicuità del modo di dire sono tali che ogni parlata locale può appropriarselo, e aggiornarlo, sostituendo l’obsoleta carriola col _flipper_. Da me (provincia di Verona) si dice «Se me nono gavéa le rue, l’iera un cariolon» («Se mio nonno aveva le ruote…»). Riguardo all’uso dell’imperfetto indicativo nel periodo ipotetico, e all’opportunità di variare il registro secondo la situazione comunicativa, concordo in pieno con @DaG.

Comment: Io adoro..."Se mia nonna avesse le ruote sarebbe una Rolls-Royce "truccata" "

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Tommy!  Quello che hai scritto non è una risposta, ma un commento.

Comment: Se mia nonna avesse le ruote sarebbe certamente una carriola, e io sarei uno skateboard

Comment: “Se mio nonno avesse 10 palle, sarebbe un biliardino!” (cit.)

Comment: आत्याबाईंना मिश्या असत्या तर... This is how it goes in Marathi: "If auntie† had a mustache..." But unlike in other languages, we somehow don't complete the sentence... thus leaving the other person imagine and decide what would happen if indeed auntie had a mustache. I guess one would call her uncle! :-) _____
† आत्या /atya/ = father's sister

Answer (score 8):

## Probable Origin

[Elyse Bruce](https://idiomation.wordpress.com/2011/01/03/if-my-grandmother-had-wheels/) indicates the earliest example to be in "Jüdische Sprichwörter und Redensarten" (Jewish Proverbs and Idioms), by Ignaz Bernstein and B.W. Segel, Frankfurt, Germany 1908.

Sadly I'm unable to read the original German nor Yiddish, but the most likely version to be found there would be:

> ```
>        אויב מיין באָבע האט ווילז, זי 'ד ווערן אַ טראַמווייַ
>        Oyf mayn bobe hot vilz, zi 'd vern a tramvay.
> ```
>
> If my grandmother had wheels, she'd have been a streetcar.

According to [Adrienne E. Gusoff](http://www.bubbygram.com/yiddishglossary.htm), the above is a less vulgar version of:

> ```
>        אויף מיין באָבע האט באַללס, זי וואָלט זייַן מיין זיידע
>        Oyf mayn bobe hot balls, zi volt zayn mayn zeyde.
> ```
>
> If my grandmother had balls, she'd be my grandfather.

### Select Examples

Some equivalents of both versions of the expression seem to crop up across Europe as well as in Israel and the US.

I apologize for failing to quote in this section. New users aren't allowed to post >2 url's, and all sources are - tragically - online.

#### Spanish

> ```
>        Si mi abuela tuviera ruedas, sería una bicicleta.
> ```
>
> If my grandmother had wheels, she’d be a bicycle.

#### German

> ```
>        Wenn meine Großmutter Räder hätte, wär sie ein möbelwagen.
> ```
>
> If my grandmother had wheels, she would be a van.

#### Hebrew

> ```
>        אם לסבתא היו גלגלים, היא הייתה אוטובוס
>        Im le-sávta hayú gálgalim, hi haitá otobús.
> ```
>
> If grandmother had wheels, she'd be a bus.

#### Polish

> ```
>        Gdyby babcia miała wąsy, to byłaby dziadkiem.
> ```
>
> If grandma had a mustache, she'd be a grandpa.

#### Dutch

> ```
>        Als mijn tante kloten had gehad dan was zij mijn oom.
> ```
>
> If my aunt had balls, she'd be my uncle.

#### English

Ireland, American English (US, Midwest?)

> ```
>        If my aunt had balls, she'd be my uncle.
> ```

American English (US, Mayne/NY?)

> ```
>        If the queen had balls, she'd be the king.
> ```

American English (US)

> ```
>        If my aunt had wheels, she'd be a trolley.
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think that the origin is a macabre joke between two friends talking togheter...
When two adult persons talk, their grandmothers/grandfathers have often passed away since long and rest in peace within a *coffin*.
The joke states that should they had a weels instead of a leg or an arm, they will turn their coffin in a wheelbarrow. So that is the sencence.

Comment: Do you have a link to some version of this joke (?) on the Internet?

Comment: No, I have not. What I wrote comes from a distant past when I was a little boy and asked my father the meaning of that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Tanti anni fa a Genova si diceva (forse si dice ancora) “se mia nonna avesse le ruote, sarebbe un tramvai”. Un po' meglio come grammatica, con lo stesso risultato.

Questo può essere di qualche interesse (mia sottolineatura, usando le maiuscole).

Corriere della Sera (18-9-1997)

… Psicologia e alternative immaginarie Se mia nonna avesse le ruote... 
I paradossi dell'intelligenza. I proverbi di molti Paesi ci mettono in guardia contro la tentazione di pensare cosa sarebbe successo, se non fosse successo quello che, di fatto, e' successo. …
… "se mia nonna avesse avute le ruote..."  …
Nel gergo accademico, queste speculazioni si chiamano "controfattuali" e il loro attento studio da parte dei logici, filosofi e psicologi HA UNA LUNGA STORIA e occupa pagine e pagine di pubblicazioni. Tali ragionamenti spontanei offrono, infatti, una preziosa finestra sul modo di operare della nostra mente. Una vasta sintesi delle ricerche psicologiche in questo settore, e' stata appena pubblicata sullo Psychological Bulletin da Neil J. Roese della Northwestern University. Vi si apprendono dati curiosi e molto interessanti. Per esempio, si e' attentamente sondato il livello di soddisfazione e di orgoglio dei campioni olimpionici, sia al momento stesso della premiazione che dopo qualche anno. Il risultato, a prima vista sorprendente, e' che coloro che hanno vinto una medaglia di bronzo sono, in media, molto piu' soddisfatti di coloro che hanno vinto una medaglia d'argento. Infatti, mentre chi arriva secondo sente lo smacco di non avercela fatta, per un pelo, a vincere la medaglia d'oro, chi arriva terzo e', invece, molto soddisfatto di avercela fatta, sempre per un pelo a non essere quarto. In cuor loro, i terzi si dicono: "Pensa, avrei potuto essere quarto, e allora niente podio, niente inno nazionale, nessun ingresso nel medagliere ufficiale". Un perfetto esempio, questo, della forza del ragionamento per controfattuali, e delle sue durature conseguenze emotive. …

Answer (score -1):

**Italiano**

Qui:

http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2017/09/25/origine-significato-espressione-nonna-ruote/

l'autrice porta diversi esempi di questa frase (o frasi molto simili) che ricorrono in lingue diverse dall'italiano. Ella quindi afferma: "Alcune fonti ipotizzano che l’origine comune di queste espressioni possa essere un modo di dire yiddish". Poi non spiega quale sia questo modo di dire, tuttavia gli esempi portati mi sembra che vadano nella direzione di consolidare l'ipotesi che l'espressione che ci interessa *possa non originarsi dall'italiano* bensì potrebbe essere derivata da espressioni analoghe in altre lingue.

Ulteriore indizio in questo senso, anche se non prova provata, è il comparire di quest'espressione in inglese: "and if my grandmother had wheels, she’d be a wagon" in una puntata di Star Trek che risale ben al 1984 (il testo contiene il link al filmato).

**English**

Here:

http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2017/09/25/origine-significato-espressione-nonna-ruote/

the author reports a bunch of examples of use of this phrase (or very similar) in different languages, besides italian. Then she states: "According with some sources, the common origin of these expressions could be a yddish saying". After that, she does not explain what this saying is, however, I seem these examples go into the direction of supporting the hypothesis that our phrase *could* not originate in the Italian language and it *could* derive from other languages.

Another element to support this hypothesis, even if not a proof, is that this expression is used in English: "and if my grandmother had wheels, she’d be a wagon" in an episode of Star Trek dating back to 1984 (the text includes the link to the movie).

Comment: La pagina che citi è interessante, ma non mi pare che vi si parli dell'origine del modo di dire italiano.

Comment: @DaG: l''autore afferma "Alcune fonti ipotizzano che **l’origine comune** di queste espressioni possa essere un modo di dire yiddish": se da un lato è vero che poi non approfondisce e non esplicita questo modo di dire, dall'altro lato lascia intendere, con esempi tratti da altre lingue, che l'espressione italiana _potrebbe non originarsi dall'italiano_ bensì potrebbe essere derivata da espressioni analoghe in altre lingue.